# Two context same entities

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I use EntityFramework 6 with code first and i am trying to solve a problem with two contexts and overlapping entities.

Example:

```
Context c1 has the entities A and B
Context c2 has the entities B and C

Entity B is in c1 and c2 the same entity
Entity B has a many to many relation to entity A
Entity B has also a many to many relation to entity C

     c1      c2
  (A -- B)(B -- C)
```

I tried to solve this problem with inheriting entity B in the second context with a child class and add the relation to entity C there.

In my current approach EF tells me that the database already has the entity B (from update-database of c1) and it will stop updating context c2.

Someone got a solution or a complete different approach?

Answer (score 1):

When modelling the database using Entity Framework, sharing items with each other in different `DbContext` is actually a limitation with the EF implementation. The problem is down to EF using proxies. That is, it actually sub-classes your class with something to monitor your interaction with the database. If you move tracking from one `DbContext` to another, it will complain that you are attaching something that doesn't exist - or isn't being currently monitored.

1 approach is to just bundle it all into 1 `DbContext` - problem solved.

If you really want to divide them apart physically, you will have to move entities from one to the other manually. You will have to `.Detach()` and `.Attach()` them manually, which seems like a code-smell to me.

Comment: My current problem is before the step of doing stuff with the entities. With my mentioned design i am unable to set up the database (and therefore i am not able to use the entities). So i think your explenation descripes how to handle entities over multiple contexts, when the database is already set up.